# properties from 'application.yml' not loading for standalone application when you try to run JUnit Test against it

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have class application which run fine when you run it as spring boot application and loads the properties from `src/main/resources/application.yml` like below

```
class abc{

        @Value("${spring.host}")
        private String host;
        
    private ConnectionFactory getConnection() {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();//constructs Connection instances
    factory.setHost(host);
    return factory;
       }
     }
```

below is the application.yml details

```
spring.host: xx.xx.xx.1
```

But when you try to run junit test against above `class abc` then it doesn't upload the properties from `src/main/resources/application.yml`. Even i have also created a test file application.yml under **test directory**
`src/test/resources/application.yml` with the following details

```
spring.host: xx.xx.xx.1
```

Below is my Junit test class details

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.config.location=classpath:application.yml" })     
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.test1= xx.xx.xx.2",
    "spring.test2= 1111"
    })
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = { ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class })

public class Testclass {
   
InjectMocks
private abc ab;

@Value("${spring.test1}") /// here it is getting uploaded from src/main/resources/application.yml 
  private String test1;

@Test
public void testExecute() throws Exception {
abc.getConnection();
   }
 }
```

i am having hard time to understand and debug why the same configuration doesn't work from JUnit for loading properties from application.yml but it works well when simply run class `abc` as your standalone application.

Answer (score 0):

Your using in abc

```
@Value("${spring.host}")
```

But in the application.yaml you have

```
spring.rabbitmq.host: xx.xx.xx.1
```

Comment: i corrected that, but after the update still no effect on properties from main/resource/application.yml